# When including an interaction term, do I have to put each variable separately as control variables?

Tags: regression, modeling, econometrics, interaction

I'm new to econometrics and was wondering when including an interaction term do I have to put each variable separately as control variables?
I know this is the case for a difference in differences.

```
Y = a + B1 X1 + B2 X2 + B3 X1*X2 + e
```

However, I recently read a paper that had this regression equation

```
ln(imports) = a + B1 StringencyIndex + B2 
  CovidDeaths + B3 StringencyIndex * 
  HealthIndex + B4 CovidDeaths * HealthIndex 
  + e
```

Now, I'm curious if B3 and B4 are correct. HealthIndex is not included separately as a control variable and can we run the regression in this way as well?

Comment: You don’t *have* to do anything, but it’s typically advised to include the linear terms in order to capture any effects that the variable has on its own. It might help to include a citation for and a link to the paper so we can see what they did. For instance, if they did some kind of stepwise selection or screening based on p-values, I could believe that they wound up omitting such a feature. (That both techniques tend to be frowned upon by statisticians is really immaterial. People still do both.)

Comment: Please look at the linked question and answers. There's a good discussion of why omitting "main effects" isn't usually a good idea, although there are some circumstances when it can be OK. If that thread doesn't answer your question, please pose a question that gets directly to the issues that remain unaddressed.